# Deltaspike IllegalStateException in Wildfly 10

Tags: wildfly, deltaspike

I am currently in the process of updating my container from JBoss AS 7 to Wildfly 10.  The migration has gone well except for Deltaspike integration.  Under JBoss AS 7 AS everything was working as expected, I only needed to create custom SecurityBindingTypes and SecurityParameterBindings.  When I try to execute the same coded under Wildfly 10 I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception looking up authorizer method bean - no beans found for method [class com.mimeya.deb.security.CustomAuthorizer.doSecuredComplianceReportReadAccessCheckForUnitId]
>       at org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.Authorizer.lazyInitTargetBean(Authorizer.java:215)
>       at org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.Authorizer.authorize(Authorizer.java:174)
>       at org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.DefaultSecurityStrategy.invokeBeforeMethodInvocationAuthorizers(DefaultSecurityStrategy.java:80)
>       at org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.DefaultSecurityStrategy.execute(DefaultSecurityStrategy.java:62)
>       at org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.SecurityInterceptor.filterDeniedInvocations(SecurityInterceptor.java:44)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:74)
>       at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContext.invokeNext(WeldInvocationContext.java:83)
>       at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContext.proceed(WeldInvocationContext.java:115)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.intercept(InterceptorImpl.java:108)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:77)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:68)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:80)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
>       at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
>       ... 144 more

For reference, this is our custom SecurityBindingType:

```
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented
@SecurityBindingType
public @interface CustomSecurityBinding {}
```

And this is one of our custom SecurityParameterBindings:

```
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value={ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Documented
@SecurityParameterBinding
public @interface SecureComplianceReportReadAccessUnit {}
```

And this is an example of one of the methods I'm calling:

```
@Secures
@CustomSecurityBinding
public boolean doSecuredComplianceReportReadAccessCheckForUnit(@SecureComplianceReportReadAccessUnit Unit unit) throws Exception {
    COMPONENT component = COMPONENT.COMPLIANCE_REPORTS;
    int permission = UserPermission.READ_ACCESS;
    return manageSecurityBean.canUserPerformAction(userSessionBean.getUserAccess(), component.getDatabaseId(), permission, -1, -1, -1, unitId);
}
```

I have been reading through a bunch of the documentation but to no avail.  I've looked at the quick start guide (https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/deltaspike-authorization), the JBoss Developer forums, and the Deltaspike source code itself.  Any help or ideas to try would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.